# Azure DevOps pipeline: Visual Studio build Task ignores settings in .editorconfig

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, editorconfig

In my .NET Framework (C#) solution, I use some Roslyn analyzers, whose settings I tuned in an .editorconfig file.

When I build my solution locally in VS 2019, I get no warnings from the analyzers.

When I build the solution in an Azure DevOps pipeline task, Roslyn related warnings are generated:

[image: build task]
[image: warning in build task]

It seems to me that the DevOps pipeline task ignores the settings in the .editorconfig file. How can I make the pipeline task consider the .editorconfig file settings?

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps to resolve your issue or not :)

Comment: I have the same issue @LanceLi-MSFT. I'm trying to exclude generated code from code analysis. Works in Visual Studio but not in Azure Pipelines. `.editorconfig` is in same folder as csproj. Contents look like `[Generated/**/*.cs]`   `dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none`

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT we're using microsoft-hosted Ubuntu 18.04 agents

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make the pipeline task consider the .editorconfig file
>   settings?

We don't need to manually set anything about `.editorconfig` in pipeline, it would work automatically when it's placed under project folder. I've just tested it both in local machine and build pipeline, it should work.

So you should:

1.Navigate to Azure Devops Repos to check if the `.editorconfig` file exists in same folder with `xx.csproj` file. Pay attention to the **branch** you choose, make sure the branch you use to run build pipeline do have the `.editorconfig` file.

2.Check the content of `.editorconfig` file, check if it contains statements like this:

```
# SA1633: File should have header
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1633.severity = none
```

Your `.editorconfig` file won't suppress those warnings unless it contains this kind of definitions.

3.Try using different agents, I assume you're using self-agent. Which means you're calling your local VS instance to run the job and maybe there's something wrong with that. I suggest you can try running it with microsoft-hosted agent(choose `windows-latest`), it works well in my side. Also, update your local VS to latest version if you continue to do it using self-agent.

4.Specify the version of nuget.exe, 4.4.0 is too old. Try using 5.3.1 and above.

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: What about having just one .editorconfig in the solution folder?  Are you saying that, for a 72 project solution, I need to copy the file 72 times and put a copy in each project folder?!

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar problem today, and discovered that MSBuild 16.9 prioritizes code analysis `ruleset` files over `.editorconfig` files. So if your project refers to a ruleset that sets a rule to be an Error, but your editorconfig changes it to be a `suggestion` or `warning`, it will still treat things as an error.

Since Azure DevOps updated the version of MSBuild to 16.9, while we were still using 16.8, we had different behaviors on our local machines than what happened in our build pipeline.

Oddly enough, setting severity to `none` in the editorconfig file still seems to prevent the analyzer from complaining.

Comment: we are facing the same issue, did you find a way to override the ruleset and use your .editorconfig configurations?

Comment: @Amichai: I [ended up](https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/Fabric.SharedSettings/pull/27) removing the rulesets and putting all our default severity settings into an .editorconfig file. You can still use ruleset files, deeper-pathed editorconfig files, or [Global Analyzer Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files#global-analyzerconfig) files to override those default settings for individual projects. Any settings that aren't explicitly called out in your ruleset file will fall back to what's set in your editorconfig file.

Comment: FYI if you have `<WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>`, that also appears to override any editorconfig-level settings in MSBuild 16.9.

Comment: But .editorconfig is for Visual Studio builds, not MSBuild builds.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde: What makes you say that? MSBuild respects Roslyn analyzers, and [Code Analysis respects .editorconfig settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files).

Comment: Because there's a lot of confusing information out there regarding this, even the article you mention doesn't specify MSBuild.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde: Are you claiming that code analysis run by MSBuild doesn't respect the code analysis rules found in .editorconfig? I can tell you from experience that it does. What reason do you have to believe that it doesn't? (The lack of a specific mention in articles unrelated to MSBuild is not evidence that it doesn't.)

Comment: I'm not claiming that it does. I'm still figuring this stuff out myself.